# React Docker Image Build Takes too long time. I need to fix this

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, docker-image, react-image

The docker code is put below

```
FROM node:16.9.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy required files/folders to docker directory
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
COPY lerna.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
COPY babel.config.js /app
COPY shared /app/shared
COPY projects/tt-core /app/projects/tt-core

# Installing yarn dependicies and biuld the tt-core project
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --production=false --ignore-scripts
RUN yarn build:tt-core

# run reactjs with nginx in production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/projects/tt-core/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ssl /etc/ssl/certs

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I have run through the azure DevOps pipeline build. Logs it shows for React Image Build is mentioned as below. There are warnings showing when build is running. I have tried put the logs which show the warning. There are almost hundred and thousand lines of warning showing in the build.

```
                                                                                                                             react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2510960Z   Line 142:60:   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              eqeqeq
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2629366Z   Line 145:6:    React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'productList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2632812Z   Line 154:54:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2637882Z   Line 254:6:    React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'currentModalData.autoComplete', 'currentModalData.balance', 'currentModalData.bufferSize', 'currentModalData.cavity', 'currentModalData.cyclePerPack', 'currentModalData.description', 'currentModalData.erpWorkOrder', 'currentModalData.estimatedCompletion', 'currentModalData.fromTime', 'currentModalData.isPacking', 'currentModalData.jobProducts', 'currentModalData.operators', 'currentModalData.packingDeviceId', 'currentModalData.packingEquipmentId', 'currentModalData.plannedCompletion', 'currentModalData.plannedCycleTime', 'currentModalData.plannedStart', 'currentModalData.pulsesPerMeter', 'currentModalData.quantity', 'currentModalData.setupHours', 'currentModalData.state', 'currentModalData.tool', 'currentModalData.toolId', 'currentModalData.toolLocation', 'currentModalData.totalProduction', 'dispatch', 'form', 'isUpdate', and 'updatedProductList'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setUpdatedProductList(u => ...)' if you only need 'updatedProductList' in the 'setUpdatedProductList' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2655472Z   Line 257:57:   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              eqeqeq
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2664779Z   Line 261:6:    React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'CalculatedJobTiming', 'checkActiveMainenanceJob', and 'setJobTimingFields'. Either include them or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2672463Z   Line 267:34:   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              eqeqeq
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2684953Z   Line 272:6:    React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'ActiveMaintenanceJobsList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2688468Z   Line 278:33:   Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              eqeqeq
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2691376Z   Line 286:34:   Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2694805Z   Line 293:6:    React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'ProductsToolDataList', 'currentModalData.cavity', 'form', and 'jobModalData.cavity'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setStoredCavity' needs the current value of 'jobModalData.cavity'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2698664Z   Line 304:6:    React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'calculatePlannedDate' and 'form'. Either include them or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2701901Z   Line 318:6:    React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2704966Z   Line 323:38:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2708051Z   Line 391:26:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2711119Z   Line 452:44:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2714085Z   Line 487:47:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2719374Z   Line 505:32:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2722884Z   Line 506:54:   Expected to return a value in arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2726137Z   Line 698:6:    React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'currentModalData.totalProduction', 'currentModalData.totalRejection', and 'isUpdate'. Either include them or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2729762Z   Line 737:6:    React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'calculatePlannedDate', 'isFamilyMould', and 'storedCavity'. Either include them or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2733047Z   Line 760:53:   Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          array-callback-return
2022-09-05T10:34:04.2736135Z   Line 763:11:   Arrow function expected a return value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           array-callback-return
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is run your yarn install when you've copied package.json. That way, Docker can reuse a cached layer when you run the build again without any changes to package.json.

Like this

```
FROM node:16.9.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy required files/folders to docker directory
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
# Install yarn dependencies
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --production=false --ignore-scripts

COPY lerna.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
COPY babel.config.js /app
COPY shared /app/shared
COPY projects/tt-core /app/projects/tt-core
# Build the tt-core project
RUN yarn build:tt-core
```

If you do this, then the first build will take the same time as it does now, but subsequent builds will be faster, as long as you don't make changes to package.json or package-lock.json.

Comment: I tried to run this but this didn't worked for me. 
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c yarn build:tt-core' returned a non-zero code: 127
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 127

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM node:16.9.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy required files/folders to docker directory
COPY package.json package-lock.json lerna.json yarn.lock babel.config.js /app
COPY shared /app/shared
COPY projects/tt-core /app/projects/tt-core

# Installing yarn dependicies and biuld the tt-core project
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive --production=false --ignore-scripts \
    && yarn build:tt-core

# run reactjs with nginx in production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/projects/tt-core/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ssl /etc/ssl/certs

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This would save you a few steps in the Dockerfile and keep it more secure because there are fewer layers.
But i do not know if there is a major speed up.

Comment: I have tried to run this but this doesn't have any impact on the speed.

Comment: Do you have an estimate about how long it is building?

Comment: Yes it takes 1134.37s for the build to completes.